# How to put a dot(.) after the value like "Hair Salon.Nail Treatment.Massage." that save in phpadmin

Tags: php

this is the value of the checkbox that i create already in html and i want to put some (.) before the value

```
 if(isset($_POST['hairsalon'])) 
    {
        $hairsalon = $hairsalon'.';
    } 
    else if(isset($_POST['nail'])) 
    {
        $nail = $nail'.';
    } 
    else if(isset($_POST['massage'])) 
    {
        $massage = $massage'.';
    }
    else if(isset($_POST['spa']))
    {
        $spa = $spa'.';
    }
    else if(isset($_POST['hairandmakeup']))
    {
           $hairandmakeup = $hairandmakeup'.';
    }
    else {
    } 

 $type = $hairsalon.$nail.$masssage.$spa.$hairandmakeup;
```

and it will be concat in phpadmin. i already did this type of code but the (.) is being doubled.

```
   $hairsalon = $hairsalon".";
   $nail = $nail".";
   $massage = $massage".";
   $spa = $spa".";
   $hairandmakeup = $hairandmakeup".";

   $type = $hairsalon.$nail.$masssage.$spa.$hairandmakeup;
```

or this :

```
   $hairsalon = "{$hairsalon}.";
   $nail = "{$nail}.";
   $massage = "{$massage}.";
   $spa = "{$spa}.";
   $hairandmakeup = "{$hairandmakeup}.";

   $type = $hairsalon.$nail.$masssage.$spa.$hairandmakeup;
```

Comment: Please, sanitize your _POST fields ! This is basic security !

Comment: If any of the checkbox is missing, do you need to have empty space between dots, something like
Hair Salon..Massage...Makeup?

Comment: Do you need the final dot?

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE**

I probably misunderstand your code the first time, try with this

```
$type = '';

if(isset($_POST['hairsalon'])) 
{
    $type .= $hairsalon.'.';
} 
else if(isset($_POST['nail'])) 
{
    $type .= $nail.'.';
} 
else if(isset($_POST['massage'])) 
{
    $type .= $massage.'.';
}
else if(isset($_POST['spa']))
{
    $type .= $spa.'.';
}
else if(isset($_POST['hairandmakeup']))
{
    $type .= $hairandmakeup.'.';
}
```

and use `trim($type, ".");` if you want to remove the dot from the end

Or, as I would do...

```
$values = array();
foreach(array('hairsalon', 'nail', 'massage', 'spa', 'hairandmakeup') as $key) {
    if(isset($_POST[$key])) $values[] = $$key;
}
$type = implode('.', $values);
```

This will even prevend the final "dot"

Comment: in you first example the it's read only the first (.) like this:        Hair Salon.Nail TreatmentMassageSpaHairandMakeup

Comment: This is probably because there is missing something in the code you posted, for example where do you get the labels from, or why do oyu concat dots only if checkboxes are evaluated

Answer (score 0):

you can one more `.` for concat

```
<?php

$hairsalon = $hairsalon.".";//add one more .
$nail = $nail.".";//add one more .
$massage = $massage.".";//add one more .
$spa = $spa.".";//add one more .
$hairandmakeup = $hairandmakeup.".";//add one more .

$type = $hairsalon.$nail.$masssage.$spa.$hairandmakeup;
```